# NodeJS Execute a bash script that prompts for keyboard input

Tags: node.js, shelljs

I am trying to execute an external bash script from nodejs.

The script when executed from terminal, prompts for input, such as a password.

When executing from nodejs, i can not get it to pause to read the input.

Can not find any good info online on this.

Is this not possible?

```
var shelljs = require( 'shelljs' )

var returns     = shelljs.exec("passwd", {shell: '/bin/bash'}, {stdio:'inherit'});
```

> > passwd: conversation failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  shelljs.exec("exec </dev/tty\n passwd", ... )

  seems to work. found by accident.
```

Not sure if this is the best way though.

Not very solid i think.

Comment: Both of your posts are correct, I upvote both of them. thanks.